# Get path of current module after using RemoteThread

Tags: c++

I need to get the current path of the module where my code executed (dll). I've made a dll injection from .NET into a native process and used RemoteThread.

I have tried getcwd, GetCurrentDirectory, GetModuleHandle.
Also tried this solution. But it doesn't work either. **I get an empty string with the length of MAX_PATH**.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6719140/get-path-of-current-module-after-using-remotethread/6719210#6719210
I already opened a thread but I can not login to my email to get the id.
Sorry but anyway thanks for your answer. I will rate this time!

C# Injection

```
public static IntPtr InjectLibrary(
    Process targetProcess,
    string libraryPath)
{
    var libaryPathBytes = Encoding.GetBytes();
    var hProc = NativeMethods.OpenProcess()
    var hMemory = NativeMethods.VirtualAllocEx()
    NativeMethods.WriteProcessMemory()
    var hLoadLib = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress()
    var hThread = NativeMethods.CreateRemoteThread()


    return hThread;
}
```

---

Native Library

```
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        {
            DWORD threadId;
            CreateThread( NULL, 0, Bootstrap, NULL, 0, &threadId);
            break;
        }
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

DWORD WINAPI Bootstrap(LPVOID arg) {

    DWORD currentProcessID = GetCurrentProcessId();
    HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, currentProcessID);
    MODULEENTRY32 entry;
    Module32First(snapshot, &entry);
    MessageBox(NULL, entry.szLibPath, L"", MB_OK);//entry.szLibPath is empty string with the length if MAX_PATH like □□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□....
    HMODULE module = entry.hModule;
    wchar_t currentPath[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(module, currentPath, MAX_PATH);
    MessageBox(NULL, currentPath, L"", MB_OK);//currentPath isempty string with the length if MAX_PATH like □□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□....
    //all other options give me the same string or the executable path
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: OK, and what was the result when you tried those things? What's the _problem_?

Comment: @mandylane You still did not give us more information though on how things don't work for you, as Tomalak hinted at in your "previous" question.

Comment: are the people crazy here ? just give everybody bad ratings. sorry but @Bart i cant look all time on stackoverflow. Is 1 hour for you to long ? @interjay And i answer the reason for my double post.

Comment: @mandylane: do you have a minimum example (i.e. a code snippet) that shows your problem.  There could be many reasons why you get an empty string, a piece of code will help to see what is happening, rather than have us just guess at solutions.

Comment: @mandylane First of all I don't appreciate such attitude towards people who are trying to help you. Not just by giving answers, but even by coaching to you clarify your question. You have asked your question before, received a request for more information and then proceeded to ask the question again without providing said information. That's all I referred to and asked for, again while trying to help.

Comment: @Tom sure you re right. @Bart Nobody help me by give me bad rating because I don't spend my time refreshing this website. Believe it or not my job is to help people and I don't rate them down if there can not reach the telephone.

Comment: @mandylane, people don't rate your down for you not checking the website.  People vote you down for asking questions that can't be answered and then insulting people when they ask for clarification. (Thats why I voted you down, anyway).  You still have not edited your question so that people can help you - what exactly have you tried, I want to see the code - where exactly did Andres answer not work (just saying "it doesn't work either" doesn't help anyone help you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a "hidden" tool helper library [mentionned by Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/02/23/537856.aspx)  that gets around several quirks in the Win32 APi.  It seems you can use that to [fetch the handle to the first module associated to a process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684218%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (presumably the original executable).  You can use that handle to get the path to the executable.

Looks something like:

```
  // Get a listing of modules loaded in the process.
DWORD process = ...;
HANDLE snapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, process);
  // Get the handle to the first module loaded by that process.
MODULEENTRY32 entry;
Module32First(snapshot, &entry);
HANDLE module = entry.hModule;
    // Get the path to the executable/DLL file containing the module.
GetModuleFileName(module, ...);
```

**Edit**: I've tried a complete example.  You get an empty string using `GetModuleFileName()` because the module handle was not loaded using the `LoadLibrary()` function call.

However, it seems the `MODULEENTRY32` structure already provides the full path to the module in its `szExePath` member.  The following example works for me:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>
#include <iostream>
int main ( int, char ** )
{
        // Substitute `process` with appropriate process ID.
    const ::DWORD process = ::GetCurrentProcessId();
    const ::HANDLE snapshot =
        ::CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, process);
    if ( snapshot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE ) {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't get snapshot!" << std::endl;
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
        // Get 1st module info.
    ::MODULEENTRY32W module;
    ::ZeroMemory(&module, sizeof(module));
    module.dwSize = sizeof(module);
    const ::BOOL result = Module32FirstW(snapshot, &module);
    if ( result == FALSE )
    {
           // Handle errors.
        const ::DWORD error = ::GetLastError();
        std::cerr
            << "Couldn't get 1st module (" << error << ")."
            << std::endl;
        return (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    std::wcout
        << module.szExePath << std::endl;
       // Cleanup.
    ::CloseHandle(snapshot);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: already tried it. Get only an emtpy string. I will use IPC to get the path. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @mandylane: Updated with a working example.  Please try it out.

Comment: thanks for you time but its still doesn't working. I get the executable path with szExePath. szLibPath return me just the name of the executable. I need the injected dll path. I think there is no solution. I will accept it anyway maybe its working in other scenarios.

Comment: @mandylane: you can enumerate modules with the `Module32Next()` function on the `snapshot` handle (this example only uses the first module).  You can loop over all modules and compare the `MODULEENTRY32 W.szModule` field with a reference module name, if you have it.